# Is there a way to detect if user is PRESENT IN region or not?

Tags: ios, gps, geolocation, core-location

I am trying to detect whether a user is in office or not using CoreLocation API of iOS. It works perfectly when user enters or exits the region. The only problem is that it does not tell me when the user is IN the region or not.

Is there a work around to that?

Comment: is there any notification being called when user enters or exist region?

Comment: @SyedAliSalman yes, there is. But I want to know whether the user is IN the region. Not when he has entered.

Comment: if you could post some useful code here so that we better understand according to programming perspective